# why is animate="true" ignored when I switch between templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive

I have the following [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VCeK9x9lyZ9Gz4F0uJ4H?p=preview) (code below)

I am switching between templates in angular. each template has the `progressbar` directive from `angular-ui` project.

the first template has attribute `'animate=false'` while the rest have animate=true.

I deliberately modified the templates so they will be different from one another. 
one is blank, others have wrapping divs, etc...

however, the change in the animate attribute value, but the change is ignore. all directives use `false`.

i cannot modify the directive's implementation.

- How can i make the last 2 templates animate the progress change

here are the templates i generated

```
angular.module("myProgressBarApp").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("first.html",
    '<div>hello world</div><div><progressbar animate="false" value="progressPercentage" id="mograbi" class="progressbar"> <b>{{progressPercentage}}%</b></progressbar></div>');
      $templateCache.put("second.html",
    '<progressbar animate="true" id="guy" value="progressPercentage" type="primary" class="progressbar"> <b>{{progressPercentage}}%</b></progressbar>');
    $templateCache.put("third.html",
    'this is third');
    $templateCache.put("fourth.html",
    '<progressbar animate="true" id="guy3" value="progressPercentage" type="primary" class="progressbar"> <b>{{progressPercentage}}%</b></progressbar>');
    $templateCache.put("fifth.html",
    '<progressbar animate="true" id="guy4" value="progressPercentage" type="primary" class="progressbar"> <b>{{progressPercentage}}%</b></progressbar>');
}
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working version of what you want [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQb9f8bGEUMczsj1NvNL?p=preview). You'll notice that the general pattern i used is:

```
 $timeout( function(){
    $scope.progressPercentage = 0;
    $scope.includeRoute = "second.html"
  }, 1000);
  $timeout( function(){$scope.progressPercentage = 88;
       }, 1100);
```

Notice how i have 2 timeouts for every template; you have to give the progress bar some time to change values.

Comment: I was considering trying that also, but still think there is a bit of a bug since it works in previous version and steps like this shouldn't be required

Comment: I just looked at your plunker again. The reason your second progress bar animates is becasue you include second.html twice in row, with differnt progressPercentage values. The other cases don't animate because you are changing the progressPercentage value right BEFORE the template gets rendered, so nothing can get animated. The $scope variables get updated, and then angular runs $digest cycle and will update your templates there, so its not a bug, its just the order things happen in

Comment: indeed - instead of what you suggested, I duplicated the timeouts, one changed the includeRoute and the other set the progressPercentage. once there were 2 different sets of timeouts, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your demo works fine if you revert to prior version `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ80cNSyADwu8yonjooE?p=preview)**</kbd>

Likely best to report this as possible bug in angular-ui issue tracker